# taking an ip and getting the subnet mask, & cidr

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I have found this website calculator that explains the ip class's (A,B,C,D,E ) and also how to get the subnet mask, he was not very clear about how to configure the number of nodes (formula for figuring out the number of 'host' bits), he says 'Since you know the number of nodes, you need to find 'n'.' to get 2^6 - /26. I don't understand how he knows to use 64 nodes.

[subnet calculator](http://webtools.live2support.com/nt_subnet.php)

```
First depict the ip address in binary. Take 61.246.19.18 and convert to binary:

ip address: 00111101.11110110.00010011.00010010
First we determine what class of address it is:

If the first bit is 0 it is a Class A address If the first two bits are 10 it is a Class B address If the first three bits are 110 it is a Class C address If the first four bits are 1110 it is a Class D multicast address If the first four bits are 1111 it is a Class E experimental address

Your example is a Class A address. The default subnet mask for a Class A address is:

subnet mask: 11111111.00000000.00000000.00000000
The formula for figuring out the number of 'host' bits in a subnet mask is
2^n=(number of nodes ) (2^n means '2' to the power of 'n')
Since you know the number of nodes, you need to find 'n'.

Because you want 64 node(s), you want to leave 6 - '0' bits in the subnet mask since 64 = 2 ^ 6.
This will give you the following subnet mask:

subnet mask: 11111111.11111111.11111111.11000000
Which is referred to as /26 or in dotted decimal notation as 255.255.255.192
```

Most of the topics here i have searched say this cannot be done to find the /cidr range from a given ip address, but this webpage subnet calculator does create the range from a given ip. I understand how to convert ip to binary and also get the class subnet mask, but he did not use these to get his 64 host bits result, I think he skipped how to configure the hosts bits after he converted the class subnet mask.

also alot of the online calculators also require you to manually put the cidr range, to get the ip's range, etc. this seems to be the only calculator example i can find that will create the ip information with only the given ip address.

I need to collect the ip range from just the given ip to block a user from my website from registering, if they have already been banned for chargeback reasons. So I would like to create a php script to compare a new user ip to the banned ip's list ranges. which would determine if they are ban evading by creating new accounts.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are asking this on the wrong SE site since this is not about programming, You should ask this on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), but you need to search first since duplicate questions are deleted. [This answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) explains it all. By the way, classful networking is dead; it was killed over 20 years ago by VLSM and CIDR, and references to address classes is purely historical with no real use today.

Comment: I have read this topic once already, again he already gave the network mask to count the bits. I do not have the network mask or i would not be here asking about it.

Comment: There is a section about finding out how bit the subnet mask needs to be, titled "_Finding the required subnet masklength or netmask_." If you don't have any subnet mask information at all, you can't do IP. You either need a CIDR or subnet mask, or you need to create one from the number of hosts required. IP really only needs two pieces of information, an address and a mask, and you can derive everything else from that.

Comment: It's really just simple binary math.

Comment: I put my ip into his calculator and this is what i get:

    Subnet Mask for IP Address:

    Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.128 (/25) 
    IP Address : 108.69.154.234
    Net Block size : 128(2^7) addresses

Comment: A calculator can't give you anything but the address you put in unless it can derive the CIDR or mask, specifically entered or from the required number of hosts. The answer you have lets you have up to 126 hosts. If you know the number of hosts, you can derive the minimum mask you need to support that number of hosts. For instance, if you only need 14 hosts, you would get a subnet and masklength of `108.69.154.232/28` which gives a mask of `255.255.255.240`.

Comment: Classes are a historic concept and dead for ages. Today you can use any subnet mask with any IP address. Even if the first bit is 0, you can apply 255.255.255.0 as a subnet mask and get a class C network. And CIDR and Subnet Mask are just two different ways for describing the same piece of information, which is "how many bits of an IP address are part of the network address and how many bits of it are pat of the host address within that network". This used to be implicite a long time ago but today it's always explicit. CIDR is just shorter and less error prone than a Subnet Mask.

Answer (score 1):

From Networking point of view:

/26 means 26 Network bits and 6 hosts bits.

For simplification you can use this formula

```
Network Bits (NB) + Host Bits (HB) = 32

/26 represents netmask or we can say NB= 26, which means HB = 32-26 = 6
```

Which means you will have 64 nodes (2^HB => 2^6 = 64) in single subnet.

This simple [CIDR Tutorial](http://subnetcalculator.info/CIDR-tutorial) can be helpful.

You can also identify smallest possible network size from given IPs. 
Convert those IP to binary.Then calculate the common bits in IPs, that will be the network bits, based on which you can find subnet mask.

For example 
Let's say we have 2 IPs
192.168.24.12 and 192.168.24.76

> 192.168.24.12 in binary **11000000 10101000 00011000 0**0001100
>
> 192.168.24.76 in binary **11000000 10101000 00011000 0**1001100

```
Here first 25 bits are common bits. Which means these IPs can be from /25 subnet.
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the number of nodes is your own input. This is you saying, I have 64 machines and I need to find enough IPs for them all on my given network. Then you use this calculation method to determine the subnet mask and IP allocation.

The article does a poor job explaining this, though.

Comment: not sure if you went to the link posted, but i put my ip and he generates the cidr from just the ip i entered into it.

Comment: @ChirsG, this most likely just gives you the default subnet mask based on a class ... (which means nothing tbh ..)

Comment: Wow I just entered several IP addresses in and it makes no sense at all. Don't use that website, it's a load of BS ..

Comment: ok thanks CustomX, I was curious how that site was creating the subnet mask, it wasn't using the base class because my ip gave me /25, base class for Class A was /24. also I have talked to my cousin whos in Networking and he said you cant get the range of ip's for just that one person within his network. now he said you can block the entire network, but this would block legit traffic or other potential buyers. So ip range blocking is not going to work in my case.